# Python. The coding of a string

Tags: python

```
>>> word = '\u041a\u041e\u041b'
>>> print u'\u041a\u041e\u041b' 
КОЛ
>>> print word 
\u041a\u041e\u041b
```

How to transform string as a variable to a 
readable kind (how print word)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> print '\u041a\u041e\u041b'.decode('unicode-escape')
КОЛ
```